# Can I selectively open a module so I can refer to some of its values without qualification?

Tags: f#, module

In Haskell, I use the `Data.Map` module, and its principal type of the same name, `Data.Map.Map`, like this:

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as M
```

In F#, I want to do something similar with my `Item` module, which contains a type of the same name:

```
module Item

type Item = { Description: string }
let empty = { Description = "" }
```

I can't find a way to use this module qualified and the type unqualified. Can I use this module and type like this, from another module?

```
let getItem (): Item = Item.empty
```

**Edit:**

Adding a type alias from a client module lets me use the `Item` module with qualification and the `Item` type without qualification, but is there a better way still?

```
type Item = Item.Item
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the only way to import only a single type from a module is to use type alias (as you already noted). To get a qualified access to members of the module (under a different name), you can use module alias:

```
type Item = Item.Item // Type-alias for type(s) from module
module I = Item       // Module-alias for accessing members

// Now you can write:
let getItem() : Item = I.empty
```

I don't think there is any way for importing members from module selectively (as in Haskell), so this is probably the best option.